# Django how to save a part of model object (one attribute each time ) using ajax in views

Tags: django, ajax

I want to save an object in Django models using Ajax. But I've faced a problem in views because I have a little complicated models (as saving). The problem is when I want to save an attribute of a model I don't know how  to save the next attribute in the same model because Ajax call the view function each time we submit the form , so how to create that view function to save the attribute.
these are my models and I hope you can help me because it is very important to me: 
( when the user click on the "period" field he will fill his data and he will  hit submit, so I need to save each time one attribute of the  timetable class in the database using view function so I can save the whole timetable model)

```
class Period (models.Model):

    module = models.ForeignKey(Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modules')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='teachers')
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='classrooms')
    // I didn't put the other classes "Module","Teacher","Classroom" here 

class TimeTable(models.Model):
    // this class represent a time table for school
    first_first = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='peride_one')
    first_second = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True, related_name='perides_two')
    first_third = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True, related_name='perides_three')
    first_forth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True, related_name='perides_four')
    first_fifth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True, related_name='peride_five')
    second_first = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_six')
    second_second = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_seven')
    second_third = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_eight')
    second_forth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_nine')
    second_fifth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_ten')
    third_first = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_eleven')
    third_second = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_twelve')
    third_third = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_thirteen')
    third_forth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_fourteen')
    third_fifth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_fifteen')
    forth_first = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_sixteen')
    forth_second = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_seventeen')
    forth_third = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_eighteen')
    forth_forth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_nineteen')
    forth_fifth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_twenty')
    fifth_first = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_twentyone')
    fifth_second = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_twentytwo')
    fifth_third = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_twentythree')
    fifth_forth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_twentyfour')
    fifth_fifth = models.ManyToManyField(Period, blank=True,  related_name='perides_twentyfive')
    level = models.ForeignKey(Niveau, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a many to many field for each of the attributes in timetable? e.g. Can one timetable have multiple first_first?

Comment: Jarrett Duskey no,  each timetable object  has one first_first

Comment: Then you probably do not need to be using a many to many field for your attributes.  Look into a one to one field with reverse relation name attributes.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I need it like this and the problem is not here , as I said before I need to create a view function that can save all the attributes of the timetable model one by one and as you know the ajax can save just one attribute in my case